# Trying to pin image on map with onclick event to page, based on binding.

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8, maps

I build this code so that i have multiple pins on the map. locations and text based on binding:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <maps:Map x:Name="myMap" Loaded="myMap_Loaded">
        <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
            <toolkit:MapItemsControl Name="Items">
                <toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinate}" Tap="Pushpin_Tap_1" >
                            <toolkit:Pushpin.Template >
                                <ControlTemplate >
                                    <Canvas>
                                        <Image Source="/App;component/Assets/pin.png"
                                                    Width="48" Height="102"
                                                    Canvas.Left="-20" Canvas.Top="-102" />
                                          <Border Background="Black"  Width="200" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="border1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                            <StackPanel x:Name="_Stack1" >
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1"
                                                            Text="{Binding ID}"
                                                            Canvas.Top="-45" 
                                                            Canvas.Left="5"
                                                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle }" 
                                                            Foreground="#FF51FF00"  />

                                                <TextBlock
                                                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                            Canvas.Top="-25"
                                                            Canvas.Left="5"
                                                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextContrastStyle }" 
                                                            Foreground="Red" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                   </Canvas>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
                        </toolkit:Pushpin>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:MapItemsControl>
        </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
    </maps:Map>
</Grid>
```

Now my question is how i can make a Tab event for the pushpin based on the TextBlock1.Text (I can`t "reach" the textblock1.text in the .cs part)

```
private void Pushpin_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) 
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ExtraPage/Info.xaml?selectedItem=" + TextBlock1.Text(THIS WONT WORK) , UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

What is the best way to do this? Or am I doing it all wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access it because it's in the template.

If you want the tap event on TextBlock, just add it there instead of adding it to the pushpin. But I assume that's not really what your need.

If you want the Text value from TextBlock1, what you really want is the ID which is bound to that TextBlock. The sender for that event handler that you have is (probably) a Pushpin. So, what you really want is the DataContext of that Pushpin and the ID property of that DataContext, and from what I can tell, the DataContext is some sort of a location object, so I'll call it Location.

```
var id = ((sender as Pushpin).DataContext as Location).ID;
```

And that's what's in your TextBlock - id which you can easily use.

Change 'Location' to whatever your class is.